# Python: Filtering a List by a Condition into a new List

Tags: python

I have a list variable `my_list` which has entries of dictionaries.

```
my_list = [{'tweet':'tweet_text1','author':'twitter_name1'},
{'tweet':'tweet_text2','author':'twitter_name2'},
{'tweet':'tweet_text3','author':'twitter_name3'}]
```

I need to filter out any results under the key `'tweet'` that are less than 10 characters long, and store those values in a new variable `my_list_cleaned`

I also need to know the number of items that have been removed, and print that separately.

I've written a function that does something similar for another section, however it doesn't appear to work lists

```
def filters(x): 
    return [a for a in x.split() if len(a) > 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the short tweets using a list-comprehension.

```
my_list_cleaned = [v for v in my_list if len(v['tweet']) >= 10]
```

You can get the number of tweet removed by comparing the length of the lists

```
removed = len(my_list) - len(my_list_cleaned)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just loop over each element in my_list and check the 'tweet' key? Something like this:

```
  def filter(l):
    for d in l:
      if(len(d['tweet']) > 10):
        #do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You just iterate through the list and check the value off of the given key, 'tweet'.

```
def f(l):
 r = []
 for d in l:
  if len(d['tweet'])<=10:
   continue
  r.append(d)
 return r
```

You can use the above function to return your list. From there, you will want to make another function that compares the `len`gth of the original vs. the `len`gth of the new.... `diff = len(_old) - len(_new)`.